# Rewrite Rule. Remove Numbers from Url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Im struggling with the following nginx rewrite

I have the following url:
http://www.website.com.au/product-name-anything-13087.html

I need to remove the numbers from the end so the new url looks like

here is my failed attempt at this in nginx.

http://www.website.com.au/product-name-anything.html

```
location ~* ^/(.+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /$1 redirect;
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: Hi,

im getting a redirection loop.

Comment: Of course you get loop. You rewrite url to itself